# Extract image from Docx

Tags: c#, openxml, docx

I'm tryng to export images from docx file.
How can I convert EncodedPackage from Shape object as image?

Sample of my code:

```
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.Shape shape = imageElement.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.Shape>().FirstOrDefault();
byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(shape.EncodedPackage.Value.Replace("\n", ""));
System.Drawing.Image image;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
   image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
}
image.Save(fileName);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to extract the image from a `Vml.Shape` object? The content of the image should be in ab `ImagePart` object.

Comment: Because I thought that the image is contained in attribute gfxdata (EncodedPackage property)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image from `ImagePart`. Try this:

```
var imageParts = doc.MainDocumentPart.ImageParts;
foreach (var imagePart in imageParts)
{
      var uri = imagePart.Uri;
      var filename = uri.ToString().Split('/').Last();
      var stream = doc.Package.GetPart(uri).GetStream();

       Bitmap b = new Bitmap(stream);
       b.Save(@"C:\Extracted_Images\" + filename);
}
```

Comment: Right, so it saves images from ImagePart object, but if image is stored as EncodedPackage? How can I convert it in image? Thank you :)